# Chef Verify Error windows

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, chef-infra, test-kitchen

i am trying to kitchen test

C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-provisioning-aws-2.2.2/lib/chef/resource/aws_route53_record_set.rb:48: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Comment: >>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
>>>>>> Message: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant --version ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: stdin is not a tty
---- End output of vagrant --version ----
Ran vagrant --version returned 1
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add informations, comments are not there for that. You should take the [tour] and read [ask] also.

Comment: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.17.0/lib/kitchen/loader/yaml.rb:340:in
          `rescue in parse_yaml_string'

Answer (score 0):

`chef verify` is an internal command we (the developers of ChefDK) use as part of the packaging process. It is not for you. Do not run it.